# Convert string to list of integers

Tags: ruby

This is the input string: `1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-9\n1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1\n2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2\n1,0,1,0,1,0\n3,1,2,-2,1,-2`

I need to convert this string to lists of integers, so the output should be: `[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -9], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [3, 1, 2, -2, 1, -2]]`

My solution is:

```
text.split("\n").map do |row|
    row.split(",").map(&:to_i)
end
```

Is there a better, more efficient way?

Comment: Your solution looks simple and clean to me. I also don't believe that it can be made considerably more efficient. I don't know how fast `to_i` is. As a try, if you have a real lot of similar integers to convert, you could build on the fly a `Hash` of string-to-integer and do every conversion of an string only the first time you encounter it, but I would be surprised if this would be really faster.

Comment: If performance AND ruby are really important [write a C extension](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/doc/extension.rdoc#prepare-extconfrb). But I really doubt you need that. And IO between C and Ruby APIs may slow you down in the end.

Answer (score 0):

### Refactored as a One-Liner

I often find that when people say "more efficient" or "more elegant" they just mean *shorter* or *more compact.* There's nothing wrong with your code, and unless you're performing actions on tens of thousands of arrays I doubt efficiency is anything other than a premature optimization. That said, you *can* write a one-liner for this if you want.

For example, using Ruby 2.7.1 and *str* as your input string:

```
str.split.map { _1.split(?,).map &:to_i }
#=> [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -9], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [3, 1, 2, -2, 1, -2]]
```

If you pretty-print the result with Kernel#pp, you'll get the results you expect.

> ```
> [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -9],
>  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
>  [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
>  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
>  [3, 1, 2, -2, 1, -2]]
> ```

This isn't *better* than your existing code in any meaningful way, and I won't even claim it's faster. About all I can really say is that it's more compact and uses fewer lines, so please use your own judgment about its readability and utility value.

Comment: @UlysseBN I had written several versions. The latest wasn't the one that got saved. The correct version is now showing up properly. It doesn't change the fundamental point of my answer, though.